# How to use multiline edittext with Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using multi-line EditText in the Recycler View as the list item. My problem is that the EditText is not scrolling smoothly inside the Recycler view.

Below is the XML that I used:

For Recycler view:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/rec_actions"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/sepp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
```

For list item:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/commentbox_bgright">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_control"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minLines="4"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditTextView.setOnTouchListener { v, _ ->
  v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
  false
}
```

While Edittext on recycler view, request to not deliver touch event to its parent. This way editText will have touch event and will behave as expected

Comment: Please don't just toss out code. Instead, explain how it works, and why it's the appropriate solution. We want to educate not just answer the immediate question.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.And made little changes. I removed nestedscrollview and put edittext inside relative layout. scroll work lit bit more smoothly and didnt notice any other scroll behaviour changes so suggest to change your list item xml like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

   <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_control"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minLines="4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already tried this and  it's is not working .